# PHP can't get ajax data sent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery multiple date picker and when I send the dates selected by the user to another .php page, I get the error : undefined index : dates.  Here is my code:

```
<form action="../target.php" method="POST" id="form">
    <div id="datedisp"> //the div where the date picker is
    </div>
    <p class="set_disp_p"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /></p>
</form>
```

And the javascript:

```
 $("#form").click(function(){
            var dates_value = $('#datedisp').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../target.php',
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                data: {
                    dates : dates_value,
                },
                });    
        });
```

And finally,the php from the target.php file

```
$dates = $_POST['dates'];
if (isset($dates)) {
    echo "OK";
}
```

And the calendar:

```
$(function() {
        var dateToday = new Date();

        var disable_array = new Array();

        $("#datedisp").multiDatesPicker({
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: 365,
             onselect: function(add_array){
                arrayDates.push($('#datedisp').val());
            },
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                return [disable_array.indexOf(string) == -1]
            },
            monthNames: ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"],
            dayNamesMin: ["Di", "Lu", "Ma", "Me", "Je", "Ve", "Sa"],
            firstDay: 1,
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"

        });          });
```

The error is on the target.php page.

Does anyone can help me?
    Thank you very much

Comment: First of all add a `;` after `echo "OK"`

Comment: Yes i forgot it...

Comment: If the problem is in the target.php it is not in the code you provided. Also, you JS code have a problem. `$("#form").click` should be `$("#submit").click` or something.

Comment: I've very curious why you are getting a warning about undefined index of dates, when you show you ARE using `isset($_POST['dates'])` ... ???

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't copy the great code. Sorry about this I'm updating the question

Comment: I dont know what kind of datepicker you are using, but try this: `$('#datedisp input').val()`

Comment: I guess if you copy/past the html getting from your browser i pretty sure that will reveal more html than your example `<form action="../target.php" method="POST" id="form">`. because JavaScript can create new html element **by append way**

Comment: With the browser dev tools as well, you can see exactly what the ajax call is sending to the server under the network tab. To make sure its sending what you think it should. And also check the console for errors too.

Comment: Inside your click function do a `console.log(dates_value)` before the ajax call and share with us what is shown in console. The reason the PHP errors is because dates_value is likely `null/undefined`.

Comment: Try using the Google Developer Tools if you are using Google Chrome browser, and look at the data you are sending via ajax, and see whether the data is getting passed or not. Example: http://prntscr.com/h3lysu Also, trying doing the `var_dump($_POST);` in your `target.php` file to see all the data being submitted via the POST method

Comment: `action="../target.php"` but `url: 'target.php'` (?)

Comment: The console.log gives me the good values of date and the var_dump gives me this : array(1) { ["submit"]=> string(4) "Send" }

Comment: You are performing two requests:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete code:

```
<form action="../target.php" method="POST" id="form">
<div id="datedisp"> //the div where the date picker is
    <input id="datedisp_input" >
</div>
<p class="set_disp_p"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" onclick="return false;"/></p>
```

And the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submit").click(function(){        

    var dates_value = $('#datedisp_input').val();

     $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $("#form").attr('action'),
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                data: {
                    dates : dates_value,
                },

            }); 


        });
</script>
```

Note the "onclick" event in the button tag.
The server side code is working well.

Comment: <input id="datedisp_input" > need a 'name' attribute.  Form values are passed by name attribute.

Comment: I tried this and i can see  with the developer tool the data is sending but when i go to the target.php page, I still have the same error...

Comment: @CharlesEF not in this case because the OP is sending data via AJAX.

Comment: @J.Pelle but is the page being redirected?

Comment: Not since i add return false

Comment: How do you see the response of the AJAX request?

Comment: You mean how do i try to get it with php?

Comment: Yes, I can see any echoed value in server side using the developer tools of my browser.

Comment: Actually, when I use the chrome developer tool, I can see that the data is sending correctly: in the network tab, i can see the target.php displaying after clicking on my "send" button and with the preview i can see that everything is ok. Thought, when i redirect the user on my target.php after sending the ajax data it seems that the data has not been sent...

Comment: How do you redirect the user? You should do it programmatically.

Comment: I redirect the user simply by deleting the onsubmit="return false;"

Comment: I also tried to keep the onsubmit="return false;" and to redirect in the ajax by using:    success :  function(){          window.location.href="../target.php"; }   But it still doesn't work...

Comment: So you don't need the AJAX call. Please, post the code of the calendar object.

Comment: You should see the altField option in the docs. That's what you need.

Comment: I didn't even think to this! That works perfectly well. Thank you very much for help

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please mark the answer as useful.